# Error in Pspice simlation

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver, pspice

I am trying to study the effects of false turn on due to dv/dt changes. Here is my partial circuit on Pspice.
[image]

The error I am getting on simulation is

ERROR(ORPSIM-15143): Voltage source and/or inductor loop involving X_U2.E_E158. You may break the loop by adding a series resistance.

I checked for any voltage source shorts, but I didn't find any. What is wrong?

Here is the second driver ic
[image]

Comment: The subcircuit for U2 is complaining that it's creating loops with infinite conductance.  Try adding some series resistance on the order of 10mΩ to V7 and V11.  If that moves things along, it might start complaining about U12, so try the same thing with V24 and V22.

Comment: No, it's still not working

Comment: Why are you not applying Gate drive directly between the MOSFET Gate and Source?

Comment: What @SteKulov says. Add series resistances to *all* the voltage sources connected to the IC. Somewhere inside the subcircuit for the IC there's either a voltage source, or an inductor, and your external connection of another voltage source results in two zero internal resistance sources connected in parallel. That results in an infinite amount of current, which cannot be calculated, so the SPICE engine complains about `Voltage source and/or inductor loop`. BTW, any shunt cap across a voltage source is useless, unless there's some series resistance between, so `C2`, `C4` and `C5` play no part.

Comment: I'll try adding resistances to all the sources.I think my major problem here is that the top gate driver and lower gate driver must be isolated, similar to how in each leg of a 3ph Inverter the 2 switches are isolated to prevent shoot through. How do I implement this?

Comment: Rather than adding resistances by scatter-gun, why not look at node E_E158 inside the U2 model and seeing where the problem is, or aht least which pins it connects to?

Comment: @BrianDrummond I did that already, and saw that E_E158 included equations which involved VCC, but suggested doing it to the source connected to AIN too just in case I missed something.

Comment: @SteKulov I'm new to Pspice, I can't seem to figure out how to see the subcircuit. Could you help?

Comment: @SM32 All I did was open up the .LIB file I got from TI's website (https://www.ti.com/lit/zip/slum717) in a text editor, but I honestly wouldn't bother with that since it's extremely difficult to decipher if you're a beginner.  Another potential problem I noticed is that you have nets which are named the same between both copies of the circuit.  These nodes are logically connected together.  If that's not what you want, then you need to rename them on the bottom circuit to something like VCC2, APWM2, OUTH2, OUTL2, CLAMPE2, etc.

Comment: @SteKulov If only you had pointed that net name error earlier !! Yes, this was the reason it was stuck till now, I changed it a while ago and now it's fine.Another mistake I had made earlier (before I posted the question,but shared the wrong pic) is the COM is essentially the ground, so that should be connected to source of U11.

Comment: @SM32 Sorry, man.  Reason why likely nobody brought it up was that it's such a trivial thing and also unclear if that's what you wanted to do or not.  Anything you drew like that in a schematic would not make sense when you proceed to lay it out on a PCB.  Not really a SPICE problem, but a schematic drafting error.